# KVM or QEMU_KVM or QEMU_SYSTEM_x86_64 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a clean fresh updated install of 13.04 server with no graphical display just CLI. I want to run a couple of Windows and Linux guests so did some research and it looked like KVM was the way to go.

KVM is a bit confusing, documentation refers to KVM and QEMU often interchangeably. I had been using Webmin and came across the Cloudmin management tools to control KVM and they seemed pretty good. They also had an install script which seemed to simplify things so I went that way.

Ran the script, it installed KVM and Cloudmin and attempted to setup bridging but made a bit of a mess of the interfaces file which I easily sorted out. Running Cloudmin and it all looked straight forward however when I go to create and launch a guest I get the following error:

```
kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
```

I can't figure out how I switch the virtualisation to the above despite having read a ton of threads. When I launch KVM from the CLI I get a little more info

```
root@ubuntux64:/# kvm 
W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead 
Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting
```

Which confuses me a bit as it appears to only be a warning and the fatal error is a video device issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you have at hand starts with `kvm`. Enter the same command but replace `kvm` with `qemu-system-x86_64`.

I'm not sure from which Ubuntu release (I haven't used KVM for a while), but the binary to run the program itself was switched hence the error. As far as I'm aware the syntax remains the same, though you can make sure of it with `man qemu-system-x86_64`.

**Reference**

- http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO1